# Correct way to handle max of independent and dependent async/await jobs (Promises)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have four asynchronous processes that fetch from different sources, namely process A, B, C and D.

Process A, B and C are independent of each other, but D depends on data from C.

As far as possible, I want A and B to be fetched independently on C and D, but I want to keep the result of A, B, C and D for the procedure that follows.

So I'm trying to come up with the correct way to express this functionality.

Something like

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled([A, B, C]);
const resultD = await D(results[2].value);
```

means that I'm waiting to perform D until A, B, C are all finished, but in this case A or B might take significantly more time than C.

Likewise,

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled([A, B, C, D(await C)]);
```

Doesn't seem quite right? I don't want C performed twice, and I also want to keep the result.

What would be the correct way to go about solving this elegantly?

Comment: You can create a function that fetches `C` and then `D`, let's say `fetchCD`, and then in your main function you do `Promise.all([fetch(A), fetch(B), fetchCD()])`.

Comment: You'll want to use `Promise.all([A(), B(), C().then(D)])`

Comment: Do you need `results` to contain the result from C?

Comment: Yes I need the results from C, though it doesn't necessarily need to be part of the results object

Answer (score 1):

You can group `C` and `D` together and resolve it with `A` and `B`.

Let's understand the snippet below:

Consider the functions `A`, `B`, `C` & `D` equivalent to fetching from four different APIs. Also, notice how `D` needs some data, that it would get from `C`.

And in the `main` function we're resolving `A`, `B` independently and we're resolving `D` only after `C` has finished.

```js
const sleep = (delay, data) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(data), delay));

const A = () => sleep(100).then(() => "A")
const B = () => sleep(200).then(() => "B")
const C = () => sleep(100).then(() => "C")
const D = (inp) => sleep(100).then(() => inp + "D")


function main() {
  const promises = [A(), B(), C().then(res => D(res))];
  Promise.all(promises).then(console.log);
}

main();
```

*You can also use `Promise.allSettled` but make sure you understand the difference between `allSettled` and `all`.*